# How to convert DateTimeOffset to midnight in a specific time zone

Tags: c#

Given a `DateTimeOffset` and a `TimeZoneInfo`, how can I convert that specific point in time instant to start of day in the given time zone?

Example:

```
public static DateTimeOffset AtMidnightInTimeZone(this DateTimeOffset date, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
{
    return ?;
}

[Fact]
public void AtMidnightInTimeZone()
{
    // Arrange
    var dateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-06-28T13:00:00+00:00");
    var timeZone = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Europe/Paris");

    // Act
    var date = dateTime.AtMidnightInTimeZone(timeZone);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(DateTimeOffset.Parse("2020-06-28T00:00:00+02:00"), date);
}
```

Comment: I would have suggested `date.Date` but that might be weird for an arbitrary time zone. Maybe `var x = date.ToOffset(timeZone); return x - x.TimeOfDay;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static DateTimeOffset AtMidnightInTimeZone(DateTimeOffset date, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
{
    var convertedDateTimeOffSet = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, timeZone);
        var midNightTime = new DateTimeOffset(convertedDateTimeOffSet.Date, convertedDateTimeOffSet.Offset);
        return midNightTime;
}
```

Also see here:
[How to create a DateTimeOffset set to Midnight in Pacific Standard Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301885/how-to-create-a-datetimeoffset-set-to-midnight-in-pacific-standard-time/21238482)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones

**EDIT:** This should work. It will convert the current DateTimeOffSet to given TimeZone and then using Offset property will get the Date of converted  DateTimeOffSet which is midnight

Comment: Are you sure that works if the original date is not UTC or the machine local timezone? Since date.Date will give an unspecified kind, which `new DateTimeOffset` would assume is local?

Comment: I'm not sure that works for all cases. If the input is UTC e.g. "2020-06-28T23:00:00+00:00" and time zone "Europe/Paris", that would return midnight of 28th instead of the expected 29th.